# Sass Disable Source Maps

Tags: sass

Is there a way with the new Sass (3.3+) to disable the source maps by default? Right now I keep getting `main.css.map` (403 Forbidden) when I view inspector. It looks like it gets generated by default, but I would like to disable it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using sass via console? sass --watch... or any tool like Grunt, Gulp ?

Comment: I'm using Grunt with grunt-contrib-compass.

Comment: Did you try to add _sourcemap: false_ in your Gruntfile? In the options value of compass config.

Answer (score 2):

The grunt-contrib-sass module accepts a property in 'options' called 'sourcemap'.

```
grunt.initConfig({
  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        'main.css': 'main.scss'
      },
      options: {
        'sourcemap': 'none'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass#sourcemap)

Setting the value to "none" should prevent the creation of a sourcemap.

Answer (score 1):

The `'sourcemap': 'none'` option will no longer be valid as it was true for Ruby SASS which is no longer supported.

Use one of the following ways instead:

```js
options: {
    'no-source-map': ''
}
```

OR

```js
options: {
    sourceMap: false
}
```